# Is there a way to find out the 2 X 2 contingency table consisting of the count of values by applying a condition from two dataframe

Tags: r, python, pandas

I have two 2-D dataframes of same size say 7x8.
All the elements of the two dataframes have positive values including zero.
Now I want to generate a 2 X 2 contingency table having the count of

1. Dataframe1 >= 0.5, Dataframe2 < 0.5
2. Dataframe1 >= 0.5, Dataframe2 < 0.5
3. Dataframe1 < 0.5, Dataframe2 >= 0.5
4. Dataframe1 < 0.5, Dataframe2 < 0.5

What I did was
First I converted the dataframe element to boolean True and False by applying the condition <0.5.
Then I used pandas.crosstab()

```
for n in range(0,7,1):
    dataset_table = pd.crosstab(Dataframe1.iloc[n,:], Dataframe2.iloc[n,:])
```

But the output I am getting is not as expected.

Comment: Do you want a solution in R or in Python?

Answer (score 0):

In `R`:

```r
r$> df1 = matrix(abs(rnorm(56)), ncol=8)

r$> df1
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]
[1,] 0.6682226 0.28241557 0.5901378 1.696255424 1.15175209 0.09703355 2.19960689 1.24322308
[2,] 0.4292422 0.17410847 0.1386954 1.144642930 0.04136281 0.65336015 0.87096966 0.02833218
[3,] 0.2607852 0.38836475 1.6194349 0.075573893 0.05496483 0.79193135 0.06270197 0.27005351
[4,] 0.7138614 0.05287644 1.4908293 0.002939561 0.63763549 1.10267168 0.35231624 1.50496824
[5,] 1.5098917 0.34357701 1.2088188 0.156056992 1.78005524 1.17668895 0.94442872 0.17400636
[6,] 0.3226403 0.96436612 0.3732588 1.153397271 0.96510419 1.29678564 0.76600552 1.14121959
[7,] 1.6525685 0.96891763 1.0595267 0.915958269 0.33973163 0.39156703 1.32788981 0.70132812

r$> df2 = matrix(abs(rnorm(56)), ncol=8)

r$> df2
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]
[1,] 0.501127933 0.6794553 1.6995552 1.92459532 1.6368866 0.58981996 2.24184997 0.47459565
[2,] 3.048202447 1.8427615 0.9233082 0.99768893 0.5749321 0.07858684 0.75975192 0.85670627
[3,] 0.240762675 1.0288162 1.4731324 1.74728557 0.3792198 1.45571644 1.44276715 1.28603166
[4,] 0.008688401 0.5616441 1.7215643 0.68260801 0.3687683 0.05059589 0.86333468 1.33624547
[5,] 0.239198951 0.6257324 0.1917872 0.03031718 0.5610879 1.78274920 0.02840848 1.96539331
[6,] 0.970775877 1.0268619 1.3544265 0.28405792 2.0291795 1.27694060 0.83879726 0.02895018
[7,] 0.954755538 0.7014218 0.2447225 0.80401032 1.3847308 0.16629323 1.04782413 0.97869584

r$> b1 = df1 >= .5

r$> b1
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[7,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

r$> b2 = df2 >= .5

r$> b2
      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
[1,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[6,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[7,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

r$> table(b1, b2)
       b2
b1      FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     4   19
  TRUE     11   22
```

In python

```py
>>> from datar.all import *
>>> df1 = tibble(*(abs(rnorm(7)) for i in range(8)))
>>> df1
      _Var0     _Var1     _Var2     _Var3     _Var4     _Var5     _Var6     _Var7
  <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64>
0  0.580735  0.055412  2.864551  0.188232  0.096587  0.911046  0.433140  1.228260
1  0.009127  0.895873  1.463966  0.327995  0.490161  0.995679  1.672227  0.206691
2  1.078921  0.877574  1.225630  1.597665  1.479425  0.606382  0.113844  0.812796
3  0.399815  1.696251  0.280670  1.374947  1.479824  0.809162  1.401273  1.411575
4  1.423431  1.183043  1.327083  2.621048  1.332747  0.716064  0.495391  0.270472
5  0.378197  0.783956  0.731356  0.941908  0.229729  0.092282  0.826680  0.802166
6  0.211048  0.236850  0.598190  0.264912  0.310567  1.812378  1.507889  1.394628
>>> df2 = tibble(*(abs(rnorm(7)) for i in range(8)))
>>> df2
      _Var0     _Var1     _Var2     _Var3     _Var4     _Var5     _Var6     _Var7
  <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64> <float64>
0  0.231077  2.534415  1.042360  0.971305  0.187516  0.283344  1.300022  1.850536
1  0.173361  0.973060  0.142895  1.007547  0.372995  0.614056  0.482475  0.530541
2  0.646364  0.258764  0.409077  2.600854  0.308043  0.739466  0.128824  0.070984
3  0.141725  0.846848  0.698104  0.795093  0.398908  1.233604  0.349653  0.545371
4  0.598475  0.503683  1.850920  0.573636  0.841268  0.232676  0.833298  0.022144
5  0.018029  1.053953  0.605972  0.288136  0.755884  1.073576  1.021195  2.155831
6  0.408813  0.212032  1.233138  1.032466  0.896606  0.498559  0.437267  0.062903
>>> b1 = df1 >= .5
>>> b1
   _Var0  _Var1  _Var2  _Var3  _Var4  _Var5  _Var6  _Var7
  <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool>
0   True  False   True  False  False   True  False   True
1  False   True   True  False  False   True   True  False
2   True   True   True   True   True   True  False   True
3  False   True  False   True   True   True   True   True
4   True   True   True   True   True   True  False  False
5  False   True   True   True  False  False   True   True
6  False  False   True  False  False   True   True   True
>>> b2 = df2 >= .5
>>> b2
   _Var0  _Var1  _Var2  _Var3  _Var4  _Var5  _Var6  _Var7
  <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool> <bool>
0  False   True   True   True  False  False   True   True
1  False   True  False   True  False   True  False   True
2   True  False  False   True  False   True  False  False
3  False   True   True   True  False   True  False   True
4   True   True   True   True   True  False   True  False
5  False   True   True  False   True   True   True   True
6  False  False   True   True   True  False  False  False
>>> table(flatten(b1), flatten(b2))
        False    True
col_0                
row_0 <int64> <int64>
False       9      11
True       15      21
```

[`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) is backended by pandas and implements `dplyr`-like syntax for data operation.

I am the author of the package.